# AttributeError when using a class's method in another class's method

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

**Update:** I originally had an issue calling the ProofApp's change_screen method in the DrawerList class's set_color_item method. I finally found a way that works. This was the error that I received:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ProofApp' has no attribute 'list_items'
```

Here is a very simplified view of the original code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem, TwoLineListItem, ThreeLineListItem, ThreeLineIconListItem, \
    OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.core.window import Window
from proof_nav import proof_helper
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    def set_color_item(self, instance_item):
        instance_item.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color

        if instance_item.text == "Proofs":
            self.parent.parent.nav_drawer.set_state('close')
            self.parent.parent.screen_manager.current = 'screen2'
            ProofApp.change_screen(ProofApp, instance_item)


class ProofApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_items = {
        'drawer_items': {
            "Menu": {'icon': "home", 'screen': 'menu'},
            "Starred": {'icon': "star", 'screen': 'menu'},
            "Proofs": {'icon': "folder", 'screen': 'screen2'},
            "Other": {'icon': "android", 'screen': 'menu'}
            }
          }

    

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(proof_helper)
        return screen

    def change_screen(self, instance_item):
        if instance_item.text in self.list_items:
            print(instance_item.text)
        print("not in list")

    def on_start(self):

        self.list_items = {
            'drawer_items': {
                "Menu": {'icon': "home", 'screen': 'menu'},
                "Starred": {'icon': "star", 'screen': 'menu'},
                "Proofs": {'icon': "folder", 'screen': 'screen2'}

        }
        drawer_items = self.list_items['drawer_items']

ProofApp().run()
```

What I have done differently in my revisions was make list_items a class attribute and instantiate a ProofApp object in my DrawerList class to call the change_screen method in ProofApp.

**The updated code:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem, TwoLineListItem, ThreeLineListItem, ThreeLineIconListItem, \
    OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.core.window import Window
from proof_nav import proof_helper
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    def set_color_item(self, instance_item):
        instance_item.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color

        e1 = ProofApp()
        if instance_item.text == "Proofs":
            self.parent.parent.nav_drawer.set_state('close')
            self.parent.parent.screen_manager.current = 'screen2'
            e1.change_screen(instance_item)


class ProofApp(MDApp):
    list_items = {
            'drawer_items': {
                "Menu": {'icon': "home", 'screen': 'menu'},
                "Starred": {'icon': "star", 'screen': 'menu'},
                "Proofs": {'icon': "folder", 'screen': 'screen2'}
        }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_items = {
        'drawer_items': {
            "Menu": {'icon': "home", 'screen': 'menu'},
            "Starred": {'icon': "star", 'screen': 'menu'},
            "Proofs": {'icon': "folder", 'screen': 'screen2'},
            "Other": {'icon': "android", 'screen': 'menu'}
            }
          }



    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(proof_helper)
        return screen

    def change_screen(self, instance_item):
        if instance_item.text in self.list_items:
            print(instance_item.text)
        print("not in list")

    def on_start(self):
        drawer_items = self.list_items['drawer_items']

ProofApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Think the problem here is that, you have not made "list_items" attribute available in the object's space as at when you called "change_screen" method which belongs to the "ProofApp" class. to solve the "attribute error", you can do either of the following :

1. make sure "on_start" method of the "ProofApp" class is called before calling the "change_screen" method
2. you can override or update init method of MDApp, ProofApp's Super class.
3. you can call on_start method within the change_screen method, probably at the top

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try the overriding of init even though I came up with something different.